# FFmpeg output to MacOSX screen?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

How do I route ffmpeg output to the screen on MacOSX?

If I type:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay  output.mp4
```

The output file contains the input file with the logo overlayed on top of it.

If I type:

```
ffplay -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay
```

Then it throws the error:

```
Argument 'logo.png' provided as input filename, but 'input.mp4' was already specified.
```

...but typing:

```
ffplay -filters
```

displays a list of filters including:

```
 T.C overlay          VV->V      Overlay a video source on top of the input.
```

Clearly, I'm missing something obvious.

How do I route ffmpeg output to the screen, and where can I find a list of which filters and options work in ffmpeg but not in ffplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lots of help from Mortiz and Carl on the ffmpeg-user mailing list, I have an incantation that works in both ffmpeg and ffplay:

```
ffplay -i input.mp4 -vf movie=logo.png,[in]overlay
```

and:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf movie=logo.png,[in]overlay test.mp4
```